# .Net Core HttpClientFactory -> SocketException (11001,10054)

Tags: c#, .net, sockets, .net-core

**this is my configureservices**

```
services.AddHttpClient(ApiDataAccessConstants.InterfaceLocalApiHttpClient, (service,client) =>
        {                
            client.DefaultRequestVersion = new Version(2, 0);
        }).ConfigurePrimaryHttpMessageHandler(messageHandler =>
        {
            var handler = new SocketsHttpHandler
            {
                PooledConnectionLifetime = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(10),
                PooledConnectionIdleTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5),
          
                AutomaticDecompression = DecompressionMethods.Brotli |
                                                  DecompressionMethods.GZip |
                                                  DecompressionMethods.Deflate,
                
                
            };
            return handler;
        }); 
        services.AddHttpClient(ApiDataAccessConstants.ScraperLocalHttpClient, (service, client) =>
        {
            client.DefaultRequestVersion = new Version(2, 0);
        }).ConfigurePrimaryHttpMessageHandler(messageHandler =>
        {
            var handler = new SocketsHttpHandler
            {
                PooledConnectionLifetime = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(10),
                PooledConnectionIdleTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5),

                AutomaticDecompression = DecompressionMethods.Brotli |
                                                   DecompressionMethods.GZip |
                                                   DecompressionMethods.Deflate,

            };
            return handler;
        });
```

We have two different server api and scraper. The request for scraper is 100 per minute and 800 for API.

We use two separate HttpClientFactory.

The requests to scraper it work just fine.
But with the API we have a phenomenon that works well after the release, but over the course of the week more and more soket errors that we receive.

**Exception 1:**

System.Exception: System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: No such host is known.---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException (11001): No such host is known.at System.Net.Http.ConnectHelper.ConnectAsync(String host, Int32 port, CancellationToken cancellationToken)--- End of inner exception stack trace --- at System.Net.Http.ConnectHelper.ConnectAsync(String host, Int32 port, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.ConnectAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean allowHttp2, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.CreateHttp11ConnectionAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.GetHttpConnectionAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.SendWithRetryAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean doRequestAuth, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
at System.Net.Http.RedirectHandler.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
at System.Net.Http.DecompressionHandler.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
at Microsoft.Extensions.Http.Logging.LoggingHttpMessageHandler.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
at Microsoft.Extensions.Http.Logging.LoggingScopeHttpMessageHandler.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken) at System.Net.Http.HttpClient.FinishSendAsyncBuffered(Task`1 sendTask, HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationTokenSource cts, Boolean disposeCts)

**Exception 2:**

### System.Exception: System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: An error occurred while sending the request. --->
System.IO.IOException: Unable to read data from the transport connection: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host..

System.Net.Sockets.SocketException (10054): An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host.
--- End of inner exception stack trace ---
at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.AwaitableSocketAsyncEventArgs.ThrowException(SocketError error, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.AwaitableSocketAsyncEventArgs.GetResult(Int16 token) at System.Net.Http.HttpConnection.FillAsync()
at System.Net.Http.HttpConnection.ReadNextResponseHeaderLineAsync(Boolean foldedHeadersAllowed)
at System.Net.Http.HttpConnection.SendAsyncCore(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
--- End of inner exception stack trace ---
at System.Net.Http.HttpConnection.SendAsyncCore(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.SendWithNtConnectionAuthAsync(HttpConnection connection, HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean doRequestAuth, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.SendWithRetryAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean doRequestAuth, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
at System.Net.Http.RedirectHandler.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
at System.Net.Http.DecompressionHandler.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
at Microsoft.Extensions.Http.Logging.LoggingHttpMessageHandler.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
at Microsoft.Extensions.Http.Logging.LoggingScopeHttpMessageHandler.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken) at System.Net.Http.HttpClient.FinishSendAsyncBuffered(Task`1 sendTask, HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationTokenSource cts, Boolean disposeCts)

If someone has an idea where that is, I would be happy.

Comment: Review TLS version on your endpoint. You should use 1.2 version. Maybe you need to force your code to use a specific TLS version. 1.1 or 1.2. But 1.1 is deprecated.